# getImageData returns white image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need to read the image data from an image object in javascript.
But my code returns always a blank array (set to 255)

```
<html>
  <header>
  </header>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="imgfile" onchange="testImageData(event);" />
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <script src="./../scripts/cam.js" ></script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

Here is the script

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
function getImageData(image){
  /*
    returns Uint8ClampedArray object 
    takes an image obj
  */
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.height = image.height;
  canvas.width = image.width;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.width = image.width;
  ctx.height = image.height;
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
  return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
}

function testImageData(event){
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var img = new Image();

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    console.log('onload');
    img.src = event.target.result;
    img.onload = function(){
      context1.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height);
      var imgData = getImageData(img);
      // console.log(imgData);
      var data = imgData.data;
      for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i+=4){
        console.log(data[i],data[i+1],data[i+2],data[i+3]);
      }
    }
  };
```

In my understanding, the console.log should return me the data in RGBA.
But I'm just getting 255.

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5rKU.png)

---

### EDIT:

Okay I found a work around but I don't understand why this is working.
Instead using getImageData, I get the data directly from the drawn context1.

```
function testImageData(event){
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var img = new Image();

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    console.log('onload');
    img.src = event.target.result;
    img.onload = function(){
      context1.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height);
      var imgData = context1.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height);
      var data = imgData.data;
      for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i+=4){
        console.log(data[i],data[i+1],data[i+2],data[i+3]);
      }
    }
  };
```

So the problem must lie in creating a new canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the image to load `img.onload` you are waiting for the readers onload event...

you also forget to read the file... missed `reader.readAsDataURL`
but you don't need the filereader.

```
window.URL = window.URL || webkitURL
var img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
img.onload = function(){
  // put your image on the canvas
}
```

Comment: I'm waiting for the image to load.
I draw the image (see it in screen) and afterwards I extract the image data.
I would like to know my misunderstanding.